# How to convert List of Objects into List of String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a class, say Person with all String attributes. I have an ArrayList< Person>. I want to convert this ArrayList< Person> to List< String[]>. How Can I convert this using java?

Comment: Your question's title and body contradict each other.  Do you want to convert to an array or a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each attribute of the person class is an item in the string array, the following will do the job:

Person Class:

```
public class Person {
private String title;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Person(String title, String firstName, String lastName) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

PersonConverter Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonConverter {

public List<String[]> convertPersonList(List<Person> list) {
    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person p : list) {
        result.add(convertPerson(p));
    }

    return result;
}

private String[] convertPerson(Person p) {
    String[] persontAttributes = new String[3];
    persontAttributes[0] = p.getTitle();
    persontAttributes[1] = p.getFirstName();
    persontAttributes[2] = p.getLastName();
    return persontAttributes;
}
}
```

The Test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create a person list
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    Person john = new Person("Mr.", "John", "Lenonn");
    Person paul = new Person("Sir", "Paul", "McCartney");

    personList.add(john);
    personList.add(paul);

    //create an instance of the person converter
    PersonConverter pc = new PersonConverter();

    //perform the conversion
    List<String[]> convertedList = pc.convertPersonList(personList);

    //print the result to the console
    for (String[] stringArray : convertedList) {
        for (String s : stringArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

This prints out:

```
Mr.
John
Lenonn

Sir
Paul
McCartney
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand clearly what you're asking for but you can always make a simple loop on your persons.

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
List<String[]> everyonesAtt = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (Person person : people) {
    everyonesAtt.add(person.getAttributes());
}
```

And an example of Person class :

```
public class Person {

private String name;

private String surname;

public String[] getAttributes(){
    String[] atts = {name, surname};
    return atts;
}   
}
```